# How to display data in US Heat Map - Javascript - Laravel 5

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, dictionary, heatmap

I want to display data in a JS Heat map like this one:

[image: US Heat map]

This is the 2 diffrent types of data I'am receiving:

[image: My Listing Data]

Im getting the data like this:

```
public function index() {

        $regions = DB::table('locations')
            ->select('regionCode', DB::raw('count(id) as total'))
            ->groupBy('regionCode')
            ->get();

        $newRegions = [];

        foreach( $regions as $region ){
            $newRegions[$region->regionCode] = $region->total;
        }

        return view('admin.dashboard-v2', compact('newRegions'));
}
```

And this is how I'm SUPPOSED to display it:

```
var map = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  type: "map",
  "theme": "light",

  colorSteps: 10,

  dataProvider: {
    map: "usaLow",
    areas: [ {
      id: "US-AL",
      value: 4447100
    }, {
      id: "US-AK",
      value: 626932
    }, {
      id: "US-AZ",
      value: 5130632
    }, {
      id: "US-AR",
      value: 2673400
    }, {
      id: "US-CA",
      value: 33871648
    },.... and so on
```

Im having trouble displaying it like above: How would I display the data im getting from the array into the 'areas' section in the ChartJS script?

I tried this, but it dosen't work:

```
areas: [ {
                    id: "US-{!! json_encode(array_keys($newRegions)) !!}",
                    value: {!! json_encode(array_values($newRegions)) !!}
                } ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did:

```
$heatMap = DB::table('locations')
            ->select('regionCode', DB::raw('count(id) as total'))
            ->groupBy('regionCode')
            ->get();

$newHeatMap = [];


foreach( $heatMap as $regionH ){
   $newHeatMap[] = [ 'id' => 'US-' . $regionH->regionCode, 'value' => $regionH->total ];
}

return view('admin.dashboard-v2', compact('newHeatMap'));
```

Then In my Chart JS

```
dataProvider: {
       map: "usaLow",
       areas:  {!! json_encode(array_values($newHeatMap)) !!}
},
```

Answer (score 0):

is is a very common problem, transforming data structures to specific implementations.
the phpleague has many cool packages to help you with this.
one of my favorites is
http://fractal.thephpleague.com/

However, I want to show you in **plain PHP** how to transform **an array** into the **desired structure.**

**1)** get the array of data that you need to transform (the data that you showed in the previous image)

```
array:15[
0 => regioncode:"AL"
     total: 16]
]...
```

**2)** transform the array using the array_map function

```
 //http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php  
  $transformedarray = array_map(function ($loopdata) { 

                    return [
                        "id" => "US-".$loopdata['regionCode'],
                        "value" => $loopdata['value']                    

                    ];

                }, $regions->toArray());
```

**3)** var_dump($transformedarray) o return this array with laravel responde to check the desired structure match the one you require.

**4)** pass this variable (array) to the view using this method

```
return view('admin.dashboard-v2')->with(['newarray' => $transformedarray]);
```

**5)** if you are using BLADE try to user control structures to loop over your data
https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates

insert this code sniplet where you need the data to populate in the view

```
areas: [ 
       @foreach ($newarray as $newarr)
    {
    id:{{ $newarr->id }},
    value:{{ $newarr->value }}
    },
       @endforeach

 ]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Seems legit, but I think I found a better way to do it. Look at my answer